# How to import from a project folder that is dedicated to containing packages?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a bunch of libraries for the current project I am working on. The support libraries are called `WestPond` and `EastPond` and the main project is called `AtlanticOcean`. I don't want to install `WestPond` and `EastPond` to my `site-packages` folder because I want `site-packages` to be only for packages that weren't written by me. The folder sturcture looks like:

```
atlantic_ocean/
│ 
├── AtlanticOcean/
│   └── main.py
│   
├── scripts/
│   └── send_report.py
│ 
├── requirements.txt
│ 
│ 
└── src/
    │
    ├── WestPond
    │   └──  main.py
    │
    └── EastPond
        └──  main.py
```

Inside of `atlantic_ocean\src\WestPond\main.py` I have:

```
def main():
    return ['salmon', 'trout', 'tuna']
```

Inside of `atlantic_ocean\AtlanticOcean\main.py` I have:

```
import sys
src_path = r'C:\Users\robert_levey\pycharmprojects\atlantic_ocean\src'
sys.path.append(src_path)

from WestPond.main import main as west_pond_species
```

I feel like the current `sys.path.append` method is ugly and unpythonic. Is there a better way to import all the packages inside the `src` folder?

Ideally, there would be something like:

```
from .src import WestPond, EastPond
```